# linear-gradient is not working in firefox even with "to bottom"

Tags: css, firefox

```
background-image: linear-gradient(left top,var(--fGrad),var(--sGrad));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left top,var(--fGrad),var(--sGrad));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top,var(--fGrad),var(--sGrad));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top,var(--fGrad),var(--sGrad));
```

When I use this and inspect in Firefox, the recognized line is `-webkit-`.
and it doesn't work with "to" :

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right bottom,var(--fGrad),var(--sGrad));<br>
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom,var(--fGrad),var(--sGrad))
```

Comment: what environment are you using?

Comment: @SimonSchnell what type of environment do you mean

Comment: i tried this: `background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right bottom,red,green);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom,red,green); `And the -moz- line is used in my firefox. I have the version 50.1.0. Are you sure your vars are outputed correctly? Considering that the <br> is just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because CSS is top to bottom (for the most part), which means that the `-webkit-` line (being valid in the sense that Firefox accepts it), overwrote the -moz- **and** the normal (non-prefixed) style.

You need to make sure that `-webkit-` is above `-moz-` and both of those need to be above the normal style.

Your code needs to be:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top,var(--fGrad),var(--sGrad));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top,var(--fGrad),var(--sGrad));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left top,var(--fGrad),var(--sGrad));
background-image: linear-gradient(left top,var(--fGrad),var(--sGrad));
```

Because I don't know what you are using as your pre-processor, below is a snippet with working code (*the variables have been replaced with actual hex values*).

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ffffff, #000000);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #ffffff, #000000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left top, #ffffff, #000000);
  background-image: linear-gradient(left top, #ffffff, #000000);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I did it but know it works neither in chrome nor in firefox , I'm really confused

Comment: @KavianRabbani What are you using as your pre-processor for CSS? Is it inputting the correct values in `var(--fGrad)` and `var(--sGrad)`? I've just [tried this in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roa2hhuv/) and it worked fine for me. Added the generated code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Linear gradient With *Cross Browser* Compatibility Support

```
.class_name{
     background: #cdeb8e; /* Old browsers */
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #cdeb8e 0%, #a5c956 100%); /*  FF3.6-15 */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #cdeb8e 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
     background: linear-gradient(to right,  #cdeb8e 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cdeb8e', endColorstr='#a5c956',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
 }
```

[image: Browser Compatibility]